# Kinectv2 normalizing depth values

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am using Kinect v2 to capture the depth frames. I saw Kinect SDK 1.x  codes in C++, they used this

```
BYTE depth = 255 - (BYTE)(256*realDepth/0x0fff);
```

I want to know, what is the purpose of this command and  do I need to use this also for Kinect v2?
If I have to use this, then my code is in C#.
I am getting error  in multiplying this `256*realDepth`
Error: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type `int` and `unshort`.

For those who give downmark, please explain the reason for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line of code is used to normalize depth values, which are coded in 11 bits in the C++ API. With that command, the 11-bit representation is converted in an 8-bit one, which allows to display the depth map as a grayscale image.

Anyway, you don't need to use that line of code if you are developing your application in C#, because the API can do it for you.